# asihttprequest how to post json with SBJson?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, sbjson

I have write one method:

```
-(id)postAndParseJson:(NSMutableDictionary *)theDictionary action:(NSString *)action type:(NSString *)myType {

    NSString *newJSON = [theDictionary JSONRepresentation];
    NSLog(@"what to send: %@", newJSON);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.uat.ushi.cn/user/getProfile?user_id=3"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"to url = %@",url);
    [request appendPostData:[newJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request startSynchronous];
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];    


    NSMutableDictionary* responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"responseString = %@",responseString);



    return responseDict;
}
```

the method is simple,just post the value and parse the return value,when I run it ,I get the console output:

```
2012-05-02 12:06:29.414 Ushi.com[775:f803] what to send: {"phone":"123456","password":"123456","user_name":"tan"}
2012-05-02 12:06:29.416 Ushi.com[775:f803] to url = http://api.uat.ushi.cn/user/getProfile?user_id=3
2012-05-02 12:06:29.449 Ushi.com[775:f803] -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [<]
2012-05-02 12:06:29.449 Ushi.com[775:f803] responseString = <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request method 'POST' not supported</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Request method 'POST' not supported).</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.20</h3></body></html>
(lldb)
```

and it crash!but if I comment the line`[request appendPostData:[newJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`I will receive the data,but it also crash.
thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because what you get from server is not a valid JSON, but a plain html.

The problem is that your server does not support **POST** , so it returns error page.